# double type digits in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, range

The IEE754 (64 bits) floating point is supposed to correctly represent 15 significant digit although the internal representation has 17 ditigs. Is there a way to force the 16th and 17th digits to zero ??

Ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(VS.80).aspx  :
.
.

Remember that a floating-point number can only approximate a decimal number, and that the precision of a floating-point number determines how accurately that number approximates a decimal number. By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally. The precision of a floating-point number has several consequences:
.
.

Example nos:
 d1 = 97842111437.390091
 d2 = 97842111437.390076
d1 and d2 differ in 16th and 17th decimal places that are not supposed to be significant. Looking for ways to force them to zero. ie
 d1 = 97842111437.390000
 d2 = 97842111437.390000

Comment: Are you talking about 64-bit floats?  As in 15 significant decimal digits?

Comment: I have to agree with John W.  The question is a little vague.  The internal representation isn't in decimal at all.

Comment: IEEE754 doubles have 52 bits of mantissa: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format
Aside from Intel using 80-bit floating point registers with 64 bits of mantissa (about 19 digits of resolution), I've never heard of any different "internal representation".  Can you provide a reference to what you are referring to?

Comment: The reference to internal representation is just that the computer thinks in binary binary, not decimal; and all registers are binary, not decimal.

Answer (score 13):

No. Counter-example: the two closest floating-point numbers to a rational

```
1.11111111111118
```

(which has 15 decimal digits) are

```
1.1111111111111799942818834097124636173248291015625
1.1111111111111802163264883347437717020511627197265625
```

In other words, there is not floating-point number that starts with `1.1111111111111800`.

Answer (score 3):

This question is a little malformed.  The hardware stores the numbers
in binary, not decimal.  So in the general case you can't do precise
math in base 10.  Some decimal numbers (0.1 is one of them!) do not
even have a non-repeating representation in binary.  If you have
precision requirements like this, where you care about the number
being of known precision to exactly 15 decimal digits, you will need
to pick another representation for your numbers.

Answer (score 3):

No, but I wonder if this is relevant to any of your issues (GCC specific):

[GCC Documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

> -ffloat-store Do not store floating point variables in registers, and
>   inhibit other options that might
>   change whether a floating point value
>   is taken from a register or memory.
>
> This option prevents undesirable
>   excess precision on machines such as
>   the 68000 where the floating registers
>   (of the 68881) keep more precision
>   than a double is supposed to have.
>   Similarly for the x86 architecture.
>   For most programs, the excess
>   precision does only good, but a few
>   programs rely on the precise
>   definition of IEEE floating point. Use
>   -ffloat-store for such programs, after modifying them to store all pertinent
>   intermediate computations into
>   variables.

Comment: While the command-line option is GCC specific, the issue isn't.  I used a C compiler on 68030 and 68040 Macs that had "extended" floating-point numbers, which were just the 80-bit representations in the 68881 implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to directly modify the bits in your number by creating a union with a field for the floating point number and an integral type of the same size.  Then you can access the bits you want and set them however you want.  Here is in example where I whack the sign bit; you can choose any field you want, of course.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union double_int {
  double             fp;
  unsigned long long integer;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  double            my_double = 1325.34634;
  union double_int  *my_union = (union double_int *)&my_double;

  /* print original numbers */
  printf("Float   %f\n", my_double);
  printf("Integer %llx\n", my_union->integer);

  /* whack the sign bit to 1 */
  my_union->integer |= 1ULL << 63;

  /* print modified numbers */
  printf("Negative float   %f\n", my_double);
  printf("Negative integer %llx\n", my_union->integer);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I misread the question.... well, I'll wait for a clarification then delete this one if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, people only care about something like this ("I only want the first *x* digits") when displaying the number.  That's relatively easy with `stringstream`s or `sprintf`.

If you're concerned about comparing numbers with `==`; you really can't do that with floating point numbers.  Instead you want to see if the numbers are close enough (say, within an [`epsilon()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/) of each other).

Playing with the bits of the number directly isn't a great idea.