# Why does C++ round my double ? (eg 19.9999998 becomes 20)

Tags: c++, floating-point, numbers

I got some problem with c++ rounding my numbers...

My code is :

```
double w, semiw;
cin >> w;
semiw = w / 2.0;
cout << "w : " << w << "; semiw : " << semiw << endl;
```

which, when given the console input `19.9999998` returns :

```
w : 20; semiw : 10
```

and not

```
w : 19.9999998; semiw : 9.9999999
```

as one could expect. I'd like to keep the precision `double` is supposed to provide, which is, according to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521194/double-type-digits-in-c), 15 significant digits. How can I achieve that ? Thanks in advance for the answers :)

Comment: Floating point is not exact. I suggest you read [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't think that's related here.

Comment: Maybe not (although there's clearly some rounding happening). Still good reading though ;-)

Comment: Thanks people, I couldn't find the same question here though I kind of expected it to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) for the output:

```
cout << setprecision(16) << "w : " << w << "; semiw : " << semiw << endl;
```